# How to align icon field to top, taking as reference a primefaces component

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2, alignment

How to align icon field to top with  - Primefaces 3.2 with JSF2.

I'm dealing with a combobox that represents a complex concept to the business logic, by user side. So the field will have a icon (link with graphic image) that summon a explanation to user understand better the concept. The problem is that the icon dont stay align in the top, taking as reference the heigth of  field(combobox). bellow has the code and a image of the current representation.

Code:

```
<h:outputLink id="stockBlockedProductsWithAllStockBlockedInfo" value="#">
    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="information.png" width="16px"/>
</h:outputLink>
<p:tooltip for="stockBlockedProductsWithAllStockBlockedInfo"
    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" >
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#webcore_view['Informação']}"/>
    </span>
</p:tooltip>
```

[Observe that the info icon (i) is align to bottom of the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVJ0K.png)

Thanks to All!

Comment: Tried looking at the generated client-side html and apply some css via a browser developer tool?

Comment: I Didn't, but i tried set some style alignment directly into the p:graphicImage component, unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll Explain how i solved this task:

I setted a style vertical alignment directly by the component.

And was quite simple just add the correct style alignment:

```
style="vertical-align: top;"
```

The correct code looks like:

```
<h:outputLink id="stockBlockedProductsWithAllStockBlockedInfo" value="#">
    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="information.png" width="16px"
        style="vertical-align: top;"/>
</h:outputLink>
<p:tooltip for="stockBlockedProductsWithAllStockBlockedInfo"
    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" >
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#webcore_view['Informação']}"/>
    </span>
</p:tooltip>
```

[And the correct position is like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0dQJ.png)